# Can i pin Word, Excel or Powerpoint to start on Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.1, office-hub

Is it possible to pin Word, Excel or Powerpoint to start on Windows Phone?
I've pinned the Office hub and OneNote, but it seems i can't pin separately.

I have the last Windows Phone version: 8.10.14157.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pin the new document as the office hub is where you choose which template base a new document/file on.  It sounds like a reasonable request to be able to pin a shortcut to a template and you can request it on the windows phone [uservoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com) - the office developers do check there.

If you regularly open the same document or want one for notes then you can pin that from the context menu.

While it's a bit of a kludge you can save a blank document and pin that, you just need to remember to save it under a different name (if you need to.)

Comment: Your link seems to redirect me to the Windows Phone homepage. (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us) Is that normal?

Comment: Just did a test via a Google search result. Google points me to (https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions), which very briefly loads and then forwards me to the Windows Phone homepage. Odd.

Comment: Maybe you need to register on the uservoice system, but that is definitely the right link.  I just checked it again just to make sure.

Comment: I have take a look un uservoice, and there are some similar requests. Let's vote :)

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Phone, the Office applications are not treated as separate applications. All documents are accessed through the Office portal application. As such, you cannot individually pin the applications. To work around this, there are a couple things you can do depending on how you want to use the shortcut.

**1. Create a blank document of each type, and pin those to your Start screen.** This is what @JamesSnell has suggested, and will allow you to quickly "create" new documents of each type. To make a new document, just open the blank one via its pin and use "save as" to make a copy with a different name (and different location, if you wish).

**2. Create folders for each document type, and pin those folders to your Start screen.** This will allow you quick access to each type of document, similar to using a File -> Open dialog in the given app. This somewhat breaks what most people might consider a normal folder scheme, where folders are created according to a common purpose served by the documents stored in it instead of by their file type, but it can be a useful workaround.

Comment: 1. You have to save as each time, not what i'm looking for.
2. Then it's as fast as going to the Office hub.  
If i make a empty Word/Excel template, do you still have to save as? If you create a template in Windows it will automatically save as.

Comment: Option 2 is just a little bit faster than the Office hub in the sense that the links point you to folders that only have the type of files you're looking for. So, if it's been awhile since you've opened an Excel document, you don't have to worry about scrolling through all your Word documents first. Unfortunately, there's still no better alternative for the templates.